# Ideas for campus Internet Login mechanism?

Tags: linux, login, internet

I work at this university and I'm seeking an effective solution for an internet login mechanism.

We have a leased-link at our campus, which is shared by both staff & students. All systems (desktops + laptops + handhelds) connect to the internal network via wifi and can then get onto the net.

However, a local govt. regulation requires us to keep track of individual internet usage and hence we need a solution (pref. free / opensource) that'll enable us to implement some sort of an authentication mechanism once a user hooks onto the network.

One requirement is that the software should be able to authenticate either against LDAP or some other custom user database (MySQL based) or both.

Can anyone suggest any such software or mechanism? Most of our servers are Linux based... so something that runs off such a platform will be good.

Thanks,
m^e

Answer (score 4):

Squid proxy should be able to do this.  You will need to configure it to require logins.  There are several authenticators available.  You may need to adjust the log format to include the authenticated user id.

Comment: We're currently using squid but without any form of authentication. I'll have a look into this.

Answer (score 3):

You can setup a [transparent](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InterceptionProxy) proxy using squid. You can also setup squid to use [LDAP](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Ldap) authentication, also with [SSO](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/HelpOnAuthentication/LDAP) capabilities. Hence, you have a potential solution to the problem.

If you need to authenticate the user once he/she connects to the network via wifi, you could implement WPA-EAP authentication, using something like TTLS or PEAP to handle the authentication.

Answer (score 2):

[Pfsense](http://www.pfsense.org/) will do this for free and will allow you to use Radius as a backend whom can be used against an LDAP. It works really well and will give some a lot of other features if you ever wish to add new features or services.

Comment: radius is best way to accomplish that ... i know im working on university to :D and we use radius :D    http://www.eduroam.org/index.php?p=europe&s=sa

Comment: PfSense looks good.. but how does it perform in conjunction with a LDAP Server?

Comment: Pfsense will interface with another Radius server. After that you can interface you Radius with anything you wish including LDAP.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't free, but when I was in college we used BlueSocket appliances to do the captive portal thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are free captive portal solutions out there, for example ChilliSpot: http://www.chillispot.info/

Comment: Yup that's the one we're using now.. but it has it's own hiccups :D